# Accessing parameters of a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am calling a function with parameters from a `<script>` block in an HTML file. The function is defined in an external JS file. How can the function access and manipulate the parameters that were passed into it?

**html**

```
<script>
    myfunction({
         effect: 'fade',
         duration: '2000'
    });
</script>
```

**js file**

```
var myfunction = (function() {
     /* How to get effect and duration */
})
```

Comment: i've tried to edit your question to make it more clear. if i've misrepresented the problem, please update the question to make it more clear.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a constructor:

```
var varFunction = new myfunction('fade','2000');

function myfunction(efect,duration){
  this.efect = efect;
  this.duration = duration;
}

console.log(varFunction.efect);
```

Answer (score 0):

how to get parameter of class

```
var varFunction = new myFunction('.classname', {
    effect: 'fade',
    duration: 2000
});
```