# get parameters of function class

Tags: javascript, html

how to get parameter of class

html code

```
var varFunction = new myFunction('.classname', {
    effect: 'fade',
    duration: 2000
});
var myFunction = (function(effect) {
    alert($.param(effect));    
})
```

not need this `result = 0=.&1=c&2=l&3=a&4=s&5=s&6=n&7=a&8=m&9=e`

I need parameter effect and duration values (fade and 2000)

Comment: you asked basically the same question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43322049/i-wanna-creating-my-function-framework-but-how-to-get-option-from-html-page-to-j and got a working answer. What was wrong with that approach?

Answer (score 2):

That's not what `$.param` is for.  You're supply two formal parameters to the function, so declare it:

```
var myFunction = function(classname, options) {
    ..
}
```

and you can than access the options as:

```
var effect = options.effect;
var duration = options.duration;
```